# waits until the program is running

Tags: java

I got code below. It checks if the program is running. If the program isn't running, it will check it again, until it finds the programs is running to end the loop. And the thing is I don't know how to loop it.

```
public class Test {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String line;
        String pidInfo ="";

        Process p =Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") +"\\system32\\"+"tasklist.exe");

        try (BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                pidInfo+=line;
            }       
        }

    while(pidInfo == "msiexec.exe")
        if(pidInfo.contains("msiexec.exe")) {
            System.out.println("Notepad is running");
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(120);           
        } else {    
            System.out.println("Notepad is not running");
            loop            
        }    
    }
}
```

But the output is empty. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because your loops are wrong. First you have a loop that read the list of tasks in a single `String`. It is then unlikely to appear that this list is reduced to the single word `msiexec.exe` (please don't use `==` to test strings) so the condition of your second loop is always false (just remove the second loop, then test if `pidInfo` contains the word or not).

Comment: I want the second loop to check if msiexec.exe is running. And if its not running, it will loop again to check if it runs. The loop will be terminate if it finds specified process running. I edited my code above. 

Is there any alternative code for that?

Comment: You don't need a loop the second time! You already catched every task name in a single string. Then just test if the string contains your task name.